# Best practices on Angular2 form validation

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-directives, angular2-services, angular2-forms

I want to understand a little bit more about how NG2 RC6 handles validations for the fields, such as simple ones, and other more complex i.e.: field dependency, custom validations, etc.

I took a look at several pages, like this :

http://blog.ng-book.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-forms-in-angular-2/

But none of them specify how are the best practices, I don't like the idea of putting the messages in the templates, also I was thinking in how fields can share validation rules.

As a desired set of features i'm thinking in:

- simple validations: numbers, ranges, text-only, enumeratives, required
- custom validations
- field dependency
- rule based validations, that can be provided by the server

Comment: Take a look at this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ihYc9y7dQA0

Comment: Hey @HarryNinh thanks for the tip! i will do it!